# Use of sbb instruction and Carry Flag

Tags: assembly, x86, att, bigint

I'm studying a question applied in an assembly test and i´m having problems determining what the code is actualy doing. I'll put below what i think it is doind.

I don't understand exatly what the sbb is doing. My guess is that it´s there to trick. I think this, because the Carry Flag is never changed from 0. I´m i wrong? The carry flag is zero before de loop and nothing inside the loop change it. I´m a missing something?

The signature of the function in C is:

```
char FX (unsigned int N, unsigned int * P1, unsigned int * P2);
```

And the assembly code (using AT&T format) with my comments is:

```
FX:  pushl  %ebp            ; stacks ebp
     movl   %esp, %ebp      ; move esp to ebp
     pushl  %esi            ; stacks esi
     pushl  %edi            ; stacks edi
     movl   8(%ebp),%ecx    ; N
     movl   12(%ebp),%esi   ; *P1
     movl   16(%ebp),%edi   ; *P2
     cld                    ; Clear Direction Flag DF = 0
     clc                    ; Clear Carry Flag CF = 0
L1:  lodsl                  ; Load String gets ESI - > EAX = *P1 e P1++(because DF =0)
     sbbl   (%edi),%eax     ; eax = eax - (edi + CF) *P1 = *P1 - (*P2 - 0)
     stosl                  ; Store String saves EAX into EDI *P2 = eax e P2++
     loop   L1              ; N-- and loops L1 while N > 0
     movb   $0,%AL          ; Clear least significant 2 bytes from EAX without altering flags
     adcb   %AL,%AL         ; AL = AL + AL + CF
     popl   %edi            ; restore edi
     popl   %esi            ; restore esi
     popl   %ebp            ; restore ebp
     ret                    ; return eax
```

I think this code only copies content from a vector starting in P1 to another vector in P2, but and can't undertand why do i need the sbb, adc instructions, and why a need to worry with carry flag since there is no subtractions or additions.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: The `sbb` instruction itself changes the carry flag, causing the carry to be carried over from iteration to iteration.

Comment: "Clear least significant 2 bytes" `mov` to `al` clears only the least significant byte, not 2 bytes.

Comment: `movb   $0,%AL` and `adcb   %AL,%AL` simply gets the current state of the carry flag to `AL`. It resolves to `0 + 0 + CY`. Since the function returns `char`, it is really only returning the value of `AL` which is the state of the carry flag after the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: `movb   $0,%AL` / `adcb   %AL,%AL` is an inefficient way to do `setc %al` to return the carry-out (borrow) from the last (high) chunk, i.e. the borrow output of the whole bigint subtraction.  Since you apparently don't know that `sbb` is subtract-with-borrow, look it up in the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sbb

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a function that treats the arguments `P1` and `P2` as pointers to [BigNums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) of length `N` and computes their difference, storing it back into `P2`. It finally returns in the low 8 bits of the return value whether or not the bignum subtraction resulted in a borrow.

Before the loop, the carry flag is set to 0 by the `clc` instruction. The body of the loop consists of three statements `lodsl`, `sbbl`, and `stosl`. Each time through the loop, the `lodsl` instruction loads a word from the memory pointed to by `esi` into `eax`. The `sbbl` instruction then subtracts from `eax` the word from the memory pointed to by `edi` and also the contents of the carry bit. The first time through the loop, the carry bit will always be 0, so the `sbbl` works just like a `subl` would. But the `sbbl` may also set the carry bit as a result of the subraction. Next time around the loop, that value of the carry bit is used in the `sbbl`.

The loop is iterated `N` times, each `sbbl` using the C flag set by the previous iteration. The net effect is of subtracting two N-word bignums.